# How to embed a string in permalink structure ?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks

I am creating a custom tours and travel theme in which I have created custom post type Cities, Locations, Destinations and i am using custom permalink structure. `/%category%/%postname%/`

So now I want to append a state name or district name before that city, destination or location name. Let me make it more clear by giving you an example .

---

the current url structure is like this

[image]

and how I want it to be
[image]

In the beginning i created a custom taxonomy but some time's city, destination and location  slug clashes with custom taxonomy slugs and right now I am working with rewrite rules so is it possible by creating a new rewrite rules or do I have to do something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Wordpress specialist, but maybe this wordpress oriented stackexchange site would be of more assistance: [How to create Custom URL Routes in Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes)

Hope this helps !

Comment: yes i am trying to do it with creating new rewrite rule but not getting the desired result.